# New Bluetooth API question

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have written a small app that puts my bluetooth in discoverable mode for a long time (G1 - API 1.6). I use that along with small program on windows to lock/unlock the computer if the phone is close by. Recently i try to port this app to my nexus one but it seems like i have to pop up the message every 300s to enable device to go to discoverable mode. does anyone know how i can suppress that?

I'm ok with saying ok for the first time but not every 300s :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of discovering the phone, wouldn't it be more secure to pair the phone and the computer which would then let you search for it without the phone even being discoverable?

Comment: This is probably the only way to do that on android 2.x. There is no way to make a phone permanently discoverable on 2.x unlike 1.x.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering if you could possibly just listen for [ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED) for a change in the scan mode and then reset it if needed.

If that isn't what you are looking for, maybe there is some way to manipulate the bluetooth stack directly, however I am not too sure about that to tell you the truth.  The first option above should do the trick (almost) seamlessly.

Comment: Did you end up figuring out your fix?  I'm sure you can do it by manipulating the bluetooth stack.

Comment: I have not found a way to make it permanently discoverable on Android 2.x :(

Comment: Ralphz, unless you are going to recompile android for your device, you will not be able to maintain a permanent discoverable state.  It is a security issue to have your device always discoverable.  There is a project on google code called haggle that allows you to maintain discoverability and they even have a tutorial for how to compile android with it.  It's worth checking out if only you need your phone to have this support.